# mount nfsv4 client on debian

Tags: linux, debian, nfs

I am trying to mount a client using NFSv4.
When i run the following commands this is what i get:

```
root@ReadyNAS-Test:~# mount -t nfs4 10.10.255.119:/data/macshare /home/revivo/mountnfs
mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported
root@ReadyNAS-Test:~# mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4 10.10.255.119:/data/macshare /home/revivo/mountnfs
mount.nfs: Protocol not supported
root@ReadyNAS-Test:~#
```

showmount -e 10.10.255.119 shows:

```
root@ReadyNAS-Test:~# showmount -e 10.10.255.119
Export list for 10.10.255.119:
/data/macshare/inner *
/data/macshare       *
/home                *
```

Does the error mean the protocol is not supported by the client ? or server ? 
I installed nfs-common package on the client machine, but i dont see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is the client telling you it doesn't have support for nfsv4.

I believe it should autonegotiate to the highest working version anyway, so you should be able to just pass

```
mount -t nfs 10.10.255.119:/data/macshare /home/revivo/mountnfs
```

As for why you don't have NFSv4 on the server, you'd need to check the server itself, you can't query it from the client other than trying it as you already have.

Comment: Yes, but i want to enforce nfsv4.. mounting the way you mention will downgrade me to nfsv3, i downloaded nfs-common which should support v4, but no luck

Comment: @ilansch, is it possible to check what version is supported on the server? If it's really a Mac, knowing its OS release should possibly suffice for googling.

Comment: Then you need to find out why your server is running nfsv3, check it's version using nfsstat -c (on the server)